# Restricted length of field name

Tags: c#, arcgis, esri

How to remove the limit of 10 chars?
Implement export in shape file.

Create

```
IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)fields;

// Create field
IField field = new FieldClass();
field.Name_2 = "DATE_CREATED"; // 12 chars
field.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
field.Length_2 = 20;
fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

var fClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(featureName, fields, null, null,
esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "Shape", "");
```

Out

```
var f = fClass.CreateFeature(); 

var name = f.Fields.Field[2].Name; // 10 chars
// out name Field: DATE_CREAT
}
```

As it display the full name field?

Comment: I think 10 chars is limit in shapefile.

Comment: Correctly! 10 chars is limit in shapefile. How to create a local clone of the layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Field names cannot be longer than 10 characters. See [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geoprocessing_considerations_for_shapefile_output).
You could use field aliases if you are using ArcGIS for Desktop. Just set [AliasName](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AliasName_Property/00250000036z000000/) property on IField.

Comment: AliasName also has a limitation of 10.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. Aliases in shapefile are the same strings as field names. They are supported only in Personal, File and ArcSDE geodatabases.